# Setup an IDA (python) callback when an instruction is selected

Tags: ida, python

I am using the IDA python features, and I am trying to setup a callback. When a user selects an instruction in the hex or graph view, I want my callback to be triggered. I have browsed the docs, but I could not find anything to accomplish it.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Have you thought about using hotkeys?

Comment: @b3nj1: your best bet is to ask through the official support channel, assuming you have active maintenance. And of course it can be assumed that everybody here would be interested to see the answer (Q&A style ;)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be done, with the IDA API.  Your best bet would be to ping Chris Eagle (the author of the IDA Pro book) or Ilfak (the author of IDA Pro) and ask.  I'm 95% sure you can't do this.